# How to Import SQL Data Directly Into Encompass

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a small PHP file that will have the capabilities to import data pulled from a MySQL schema directly into an SQL table used with an Encompass account.

Encompass is a program by Ellie Mae that is used for housing loans. To simplify, it pulls in application forms to be utilized with various functions. It stores these forms in an SQL server. I understand that specifying this application may narrow the number of people this question is applicable to, but because it is a widely used application in this field and there is a huge lack of presence online for developers working with this, this question can be relevant to others.

I am making this project because currently, after my team receives a form application, it is sent and stored in a cloud-based system, where they then download the application and manually import it into Encompass. This takes a ton of time and is very error prone.

With this tool, it will pull any new forms to a display, then, after being approved, will update the table that corresponds to the Encompass account.

Unfortunately, development support is just about nonexistent online. I have no idea how to target the table used by our Encompass account to retrieve data. [The online SDK](http://help.elliemae.com/DocumentationLibrary/360/Encompass360SDKProgrammersGuide.pdf) makes no mention of how to utilize SQL, just that it uses an SQL server. [This blog post](http://ryrobes.com/sql/mortgage-software-hack-importing-contacts-into-encompass-properly-without-the-sdk-using-just-the-sql-backend/) is the closest thing I found to what I'm looking for, but I don't understand how to target the database.

I am avoiding using any of the objects mentioned in the SDK since I want to make a very lightweight application many of the not-so-technically-savvy people could use, and could be easily integrated into other projects in the future.

As a small example of what I'm doing, here is the code that targets my database. I would like to make a similar connection to the Encompass one, but I have no idea how to find out what the database name is.

```
     $link = mysqli_connect("[server]", "[username]", "[password]", "[input_schema]");
     $query = "SELECT * FROM input_schema.input_table";
     $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         ?>
         <tr id="row">
             <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['firstName']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['lastName']; ?></td>
         </tr>
```

If there is a more broadly-reaching answer to find out an applications SQL information, such as the database, I'd love to hear it as well. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I'm interested in talking to people with EllieMae experience, if you wouldn't mind having a conversation with me reach out to me at mark.squires@ramp51.com

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to directly access the Ellie Mae Encompass360 application's database directly in the way you are describing. In the current .NET Winforms smart client incarnation of the product, you MUST use the Encompass SDK to be able to programmatically read/update data. And utilizing the SDK is a quite involved endeavor. Not that it is rocket science in an absolute sense, but I found it very challenging trying to find any information to get started with the basics of the SDK. You may want to do some research on what is called "Encompass NG", which is the next generation of the Ellie Mae Encompass360 application that is a cloud web application that is all angularjs/api based. It is in development now and is expected to be generally available in end of 2018 timeframe. (Encompass360 clients would have to migrate over to it as well.) In that incarnation of the application, there will be APIs to easily load new information into Encompass such as creating loans, contacts, etc. Note that as far as I know, Ellie Mae NEVER intends to allow anyone to directly access the raw application database itself.

Comment: I'm interested in talking to people with EllieMae experience, if you wouldn't mind having a conversation with me reach out to me at mark.squires@ramp51.com